# ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'dict'

Tags: python, json, postgresql, pandas

I'm trying to insert a dataframe using the query

```
engine = create_engine('scot://pswd:xyz@ hostnumb:port/db_name')
dataframe.to_sql('table_name', engine, if_exists='replace')
```

but one column is a dictionary and I'm unable to insert it, only the column name is getting inserted. 
I tried to change the type of the column in **postgres** from text to json object. still not able to insert. 
I tried to use **json.dumps()** but still facing the issue.getting an error as "dtype: object is not JSON serializable"

Answer (score 5):

Try specifying the dtype. So in your example, you would say

```
dataframe.to_sql('table_name', engine, if_exists='replace',dtype = 
                {'relevant_column':sqlalchemy.types.JSON})
```